# R: how to choose the ith number in a data frame by ID

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my data:

```
ID         Day            advance
ID1         1              NA
ID1         1              NA
ID1         1              NA
ID1         2              0.14
ID1         2              NA
ID1         3              0.22
ID1         3              NA
ID1         3              NA
ID1         2              NA
ID1         4              -0.96
ID1         4              NA
ID2         1              NA
ID2         1              NA
ID2         2              1.54
ID3         1              NA
ID3         2              -0.48
```

I only want to choose the `advance` of the ith (i = 2 ,..., 30) `Day` of each `ID`, here is the expected result for the 2nd day:

```
ID1      0.14
ID2      1.54
ID3     -0.48
```

Hope to get your answer! Thanks!

Comment: Is it the expected output?

Comment: @ akrun Yep, that's the expected result for the 2nd day. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, try

```
no.na <- na.omit(x)
no.na[no.na$Day == 2, c("ID", "advance")]

    ID advance
4  ID1    0.14
14 ID2    1.54
16 ID3   -0.48
```

A one liner per @akrun would be

```
na.omit(x[x$Day == 2, c("ID", "advance")])
```

Comment: @akrun I generally don't use `subset` because it's advised to use it (only) interactively since non-standard evaluation (I'm paraphrasing the docs here) can lead to unanticipated results.

Comment: I understand the reason, just thought to keep it in a single line.

Comment: @akrun in that case, subsetting day 2 and omitting NAs would also be a viable tactic.

Comment: Yes, that is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df1, !is.na(advance) & Day==2) %>%
              select(-Day)
#    ID advance
#1 ID1    0.14
#2 ID2    1.54
#3 ID3   -0.48
```